# How to save passwords in PL/SQL Developer?

Tags: plsqldeveloper

I've put my database info into Tnsnames.ora, and now each time I start PL/SQL Developer I get a dropdown list of my databases, but I have to type in the password every time.

There is an option under Tools>Preferences to store passwords for multiple connections, but it doesn't seem to have any effect.  The password field is always blank when I start the application.

How can I get this to remember the password?

*I'm using PL/SQL Developer 9.0.2.1621*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After you login for the first time, password is saved.
Next time, no need to type, click on the [...] next to the UserName and select database, it will autologon. Hope it helps!

Comment: I tried this, and can switch between different saved usernames, but it is not saving the password.

Comment: My version is 8.0.1. I have it like Tools -> Preferences -> LogOnHistory -> CheckBox called Store with Passoword. [I also have store history enabled]

Answer (score 27):

Goto:- Tools-->Preferences-->Logon History--> click the check box store with history & store with password.-->Apply.

Comment: Perfect, works like a charm ! 
For version above 12.X.X, it's Configure -> Preferences -> Logon History

Answer (score 2):

It's 2019 and sqldeveloper is at version 19.2.

In case anyone, as I did, stumbles on this old but still actual question, the answer has become:

- right-click on the relevant connection in the left menu and choose Properties
- type in the pwd in the relevant input and check "Save Password"
- click on Save button
- confirm that you want to overwrite the previous description

Comment: For some reason, not working for me - I checked save password, tested connection, clicked connect and it still prompted for password

Answer (score 1):

i found the same issue with 19.1....

go to connection properties, check the box to save password.
enter the password and click save.
close the properties box.

now click save all.

this worked for me.